# Particiones BD por medio de FK

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, datatables, tablas

Resulta que tengo un trabajo y me piden particionar la tabla Persona respecto a la Ubicacion. Me dan estas dos tablas para el procedimiento, es en sql server pero no entiendo para nada esta funcionalidad. Soy nueva en esto, muchas gracias por su ayuda. :)

```
CREATE TABLE Ubicacion(
    numero int identity(1,1) primary key NOT NULL,
    pais varchar(200) NOT NULL
    provincia varchar(200) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Persona(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key NOT NULL,
    nombre varchar(500),
    cedula int,
    nacionalidad varchar(200),
    Ubicacion int NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa para ti o para quién te lo pide el concepto de particionar? ¿Estas hablando de utilizar funciones de partición? ¿Qué versión de Sql Server tienes (Select @@version)? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? En mi opinión, tal cuál lo expones, le falta un empujón, porqué tienes demasiados interrogantes en el escenario. Muy posiblemente este documento te ayude. https://www.sqlshack.com/es/particionamiento-de-tablas-de-bases-de-datos-en-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Para los que deseen saber la respuesta, ya la logré. En esta podemos notar que la partición de llaves primarias no es efectiva por lo que se utilizó provincia:

```
CREATE TABLE Ubicacion(
    numero int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    pais varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    provincia varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    primary key (numero, provincia)
) PARTITION BY provincia;

CREATE TABLE Persona(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key NOT NULL,
    nombre varchar(500),
    cedula int,
    nacionalidad varchar(200),
    provincia varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    idUbicacion int NOT NULL,
    foreign key (idUbicacion, provincia) references Ubicacion(id, provincia) 
);
```